# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 / JDBC MSSQL

Tags: jdbc, wso2

I'm just getting started with WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 on Window Server 2008 R2.

I have a MSSQL database and I've followed the Admin Guide on how to set up the system with a MSSQL database instead of using the built in H2 database.

I'm getting stuck with JDBC. I've downloaded every possible JDBC driver (4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and even 6). I have JDK 1.7u80 installed. I tried all the different sqljdbc.jar files including sqljdbc4.jar. In all cases I'm getting an error message telling me that the driver is not compatible with JDK 1.7.

[This is the WSO2 doc I was using to set up MSSQL database](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL).

I also read the Microsoft JDBC website [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff928484) and at least one of the JAR files should have worked with 1.7 according to the documentation.

The WSO2 doc says JDK 1.8 is not supported so I haven't tried this.

Any ideas anyone?

Error:

...
[2015-12-06 23:00:20,962] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -
 Database Error - Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by
 this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDB
C 4.0.
java.sql.SQLException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not support
ed by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support fo
r JDBC 4.0.
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation you can find at the link below 4.0 supports Java 5 & 6.  4.1 Supports Java 5, 6 & 7.  4.2 Supports Java 5,6,7 & 8.  So sqljdbc4.jar would not work for you if you are using 7, but the rest should.  I am assuming you updated the driver name in your master-datasources.xml file?  Are you able to share that file?  We are using sqljdbc4_1.0.0.jar and JDK 1.7 with no issues.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

Joe

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I realised the issue was that I tried a driver that was incorrect and it got copied into the <CARBON_HOME>\repository\components\dropins folder and I didn't find this until just now. After that no matter what I tried it would always load the wrong driver from this folder. I deleted all the JDBC files from there and tried again with the correct file (sqljdbc4.1.jar) and it worked.